# What `partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in Double.init<A>(_:)` crash is about?

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I give up: I have been investigating this crash that is impacting hugely my product, without finding the cause. Crashlitics shows me that this bug started on a certain date, after I released a new version, but I can't match anything with this crash.

Do you have any idea of what this could be caused from?
Can you provide an example of code that could be generating this crash?

Thank you

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000686d303ed870
0
libswiftCore.dylib
_swift_release_dealloc + 32
1
libswiftCore.dylib
bool swift::RefCounts<swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1> >::doDecrementSlow<(swift::PerformDeinit)1>(swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1>, unsigned int) + 136
2
AppName
<compiler-generated> - Line 4309475464
partial apply for closure #1 in closure #1 in Double.init<A>(_:) + 4309475464
3
libswiftCore.dylib
_swift_release_dealloc + 56
4
libswiftCore.dylib
bool swift::RefCounts<swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1> >::doDecrementSlow<(swift::PerformDeinit)1>(swift::RefCountBitsT<(swift::RefCountInlinedness)1>, unsigned int) + 136
5
libsystem_blocks.dylib
_call_dispose_helpers_excp + 48
6
libsystem_blocks.dylib
_Block_release + 252
7
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_client_callout + 20
8
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_main_queue_drain + 984
9
libdispatch.dylib
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
10
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
11
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun + 1996
12
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
13
GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal + 164
14
UIKitCore
-[UIApplication _run] + 888
15
UIKitCore
UIApplicationMain + 340
16
AppName
main.m - Line 18
main + 18
17
(Missing)
```

From Xcode:

[image]

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log - If you upload your dsyms to crashlytics, it will do it for you.  Then you will get a line number and file for the closure where the crash is occurring.  It looks like you are passing released memory to `Double()`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thx but the crash log is already entirely symbolicated. The error says "compiler generated" because is an inner code generated by the compiler. The question is when this happens.

Comment: When that happens ... for us it is hard to tell. We do not know what features you added in your recent update, or what compiler optimisation setting you are using. This could for example be just a force cast in a map function when converting from string to double. But also some objective-c stuff maybe from a library that does not properly handle nullable. Or some other actor modifying an isolated property.

Comment: Based on the alleged line number (4309475464) we can deduce that the stack frame in question has not been symbolicated correctly. Whether that's an Apple bug, a Crashlytics bug, or a user error, I don't know. Anyway, [try running your app under the address sanitizer and the thread sanitizer.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing-memory-thread-and-crash-issues-early) Also consider using a [Technical Support Incident](https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/). Your paid Apple developer account includes two of these per year (and you can buy more).

Comment: This is fully symbolicated. Even Xcode returns the same stuff. It seems that it only happens after the first app launch. on both iOS and tvOS.